# Exception occured on intalizied object in window phone 8 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm not authorized to upload error image on stackoverflow. You can see this error image on this link 
http://s24.postimg.org/5lduiutqd/error.jpg
I'm creating Facebook menu in window phone 8 on it's showing compile time error.Basically i'm using user control where create a Facebook menu and call it to mainframe.xaml...

**User Control Code**

```
 <UserControl x:Class="test.UserControls"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
                        xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
                        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                        xmlns:library="clr-namespace:SlideView.Library;assembly=SlideView.Library"
                        mc:Ignorable="d"
                        shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"
  >


<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Grid.Row="0">
    <library:SlideApplicationFrame Header="Test App" Background="White">
        <library:SlideApplicationFrame.LeftContent>
            <TextBox Name="ss" Width="200"></TextBox>
        </library:SlideApplicationFrame.LeftContent>
        <library:SlideApplicationFrame.RightContent>
            <TextBox Name="sss" Width="200"></TextBox>
        </library:SlideApplicationFrame.RightContent>
    </library:SlideApplicationFrame>
</Grid>
```

**Mainframe.xaml code**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="test.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <local:UserControls Name="SSS">          
        </local:UserControls>
    </Grid>  
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: http://s24.postimg.org/5lduiutqd/error.jpg see this link

Comment: Remove the library:SlideApplicationFrame  from the usercontrol and give it a run, if it works that means that library:SlideApplicationFrame has some error..

Comment: this  library:SlideApplicationFrame is used to display the slid up menu

Comment: Could you please upload a better image, the link you gave for error shows a very small image! Also did it work when you removed the library:SlideApplicationFrame from the UserControl code?

Comment: YES IT'S NOT WORKING WHEN I REMOVE THIS

Comment: http://awesomescreenshot.com/01f3r71ff2 try this url when u click on it's show image on popup